# How to find adress of cells for 1st, 2nd, and 3rd highest values when values could be equal 1st=2nd

Tags: excel, vba

I have situation where I need to search through a row of values, and use the cell address the top 3 largest of these values to reference the title cells above that particular cell.

I have created this formula to find the top 3 highest value cell addresses, but when there are 2 equivalent values (like there are two top values of 25) it gives me the same cell reference twice. I understand they are equivalent, but I need to get the cell address of the second top value as well. Does anyone know how I can tweak this equation or possibly use vba to do this?

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(J60:W60,MATCH(LARGE((J60:W60),1),J60:W60,0)))
=CELL("address",INDEX(J60:W60,MATCH(LARGE((J60:W60),2),J60:W60,0)))
=CELL("address",INDEX(J60:W60,MATCH(LARGE((J60:W60),3),J60:W60,0)))
```

Comment: If you've found the address of the first match, you could alter the range of Match for the second one to start one cell after the location of the first

Comment: What if there were **3** or **4** equivalent values ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent You might have to do it within VBA and loop until the MATCH doesn't return a value. To determine how many cells you would have to reserve for each you could run a `countif(Range, "=" & LARGE((J60:W60),1))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this type of formula to return an address:

```
=IFERROR(ADDRESS(ROW(lookupRow),AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(lookupRow>=LARGE(lookupRow,limitRank))*COLUMN(lookupRow),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

The named ranges should be obvious.
Enter this in some cell and fill down until you see blanks.

Not sure what you want to do with this information, but here is what this formula returns:

[image]